# Multiple multitouch monitor?

Tags: windows, display, lcd, touchscreen, input

Can we connect multiple touchscreen monitor to dual/multi-head GPU, how does the input works on Windows 7? can the O/S handle multiple input from arranged monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Since multitouch monitors simply communicate independently of what the graphics card supports, my guess is the OS handles multiple input just fine.  I'm pretty sure this is how the OS also is capable of using different calibration data for Touch and and Pen input even though the input is to the same hardware screen.

Comment: the problem is on the input of different screen, and how about the screen coordinate, does O/S will use expanded dual-screen coordinate, or local screen coordinate with "screen id"

Comment: Yes, it's similar to a mouse.  But no there is no screen id AFAIK.